# How to scale internet explorer in css hack/ media query?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries, scale

I am making my website compatible to internet explorer. How do I scale the website in internet explorer in the css hack?

Firstly I coded the website for firefox. That is why I have used some css hacks for some browsers. Now that I wanted to start to scale the website in the different browsers I started with internet explorer. I used a media query for the css hack to identify the internet explorer, but to scale the website, i need another media query. I have already tried to just 'add' the media query to that one which identifies the internet explorer and then I have copied it with `min-width` of 600, 768 and 998 but it just worked with `min-width: 600px` and ignored the other media queries. So is there another way to scale (just!) the website in internet explorer or did I code it wrong? Also I have the same question with chrome, where I did not used a media query but I still does not work there too.

```
/*IE*/ @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none){
    img.Marat {max-width: 13%;margin-left: 62%;height: auto; box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
    table.table {margin-top:15%;width:150%;margin-left:-325%;}
    .Abstand4 {margin-left:-130%;}
    img.Bild4 {margin-left:-1100%;max-width: 80%;height: auto;}
    img.Bild6 {margin-left:-410%;margin-top:8.5%;max-width: 58%;height: auto;}
}

/*Chrome*/ @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (not (overflow:-webkit-marquee))
and (not (-ms-ime-align:auto)) and (not (-moz-appearance:none)) { 
    img.Marat {max-width: 50%;margin-left: -50%;height: auto; box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}  
    table.table {margin-top:15%;width:150%;margin-left:-20%;}
    .Abstand4 {margin-left:-130%;}
    img.Bild4 {margin-left:-1100%;max-width: 80%;height: auto;}
    img.Bild6 {margin-left:-410%;margin-top:8.5%;max-width: 58%;height: auto;}
    }
}
```

I want to scale the website in internet explorer/chrome, but I do not know how to do it regarding that I had to use css hacks to identify the websites.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you use several media queries with min-width, you should put the minimum value at the first and the maximum at the last like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        /* Set the background color of body to tan */
        body {
            background-color: tan;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:600px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
            body {
                background-color: blue;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
            body {
                background-color: olive;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:998px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
            body {
                background-color: aqua;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

In this order the media queries work well on IE10+. If the order is wrong, the media queries below will not work.

In the Chrome browser, we should also follow this rule. You could refer the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        /* Set the background color of body to tan */
        body {
            background-color: tan;
        }
        @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (not (overflow:-webkit-marquee)) and (not (-ms-ime-align:auto)) and (not (-moz-appearance:none)) {
            @media screen and (min-width:600px) {
                body {
                    background-color: blue;
                }
            }


            @media screen and (min-width:768px) {
                body {
                    background-color: olive;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (min-width:998px) {
                body {
                    background-color: aqua;
                }
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```